# Does it make sense to put a firewall within a LAN to protect sensitive information from the rest of the LAN & Internet?

Tags: firewalls

I may not be using the appropriate jargon, but I'll try to explain in my own words.

My understanding is that usually a firewall is facing the internet, but my question is about a differnet setup. I'm setting up a terminal at home to interface with my office server which has sensitive information (FYI, its a small business, and I'm the IT person). At the office I have enterprise level dedicated firewall and I'm going to mirror the setup at home. However, I was thinking that it might be more secure to setup the enterprise level firewall within the home LAN such that it isolates the home/work terminal from all other devices in the home LAN. There will be a consumer grade firewall facing the internet. I might be wrong about this, but it seems less secure to have all of my household consumer devices behind the same firewall as my Home/Work terminal that is accessing sensitive information from Office server.

Is this a sensible approach? Is this an overkill, or is there a better way to isolate home/work terminal from household internet devices?

Answer (score 5):

It is a perfectly normal approach to split a network into zones (network segments) of different security requirements and have firewalls between these zones which limit the communication possible between these zones.

It is also perfectly fine to cascade firewalls, like have a firewall from your main network A to the less secure network B and from there another firewall to the even less secure internet. It actually adds security since an outside attacker would need to compromise two firewalls instead of only one (and there are still too many bugs even in commercial systems where a firewall compromise was possible from the internet).

A cascade of firewalls might give you trouble with some applications like VoIP if these firewalls are all doing NAT but from the security perspective it is fine.

Comment: I feel like I might be guilty of confirmation bias, but this is exactly what I had in mind, I wasn't aware of the term "network segments" but that's it! :) I want the "deepest" segment or zone A, to have the enterprise level NGFW, then the next outer segment Zone B, protected by typical home gateway like Ubiquiti Security Gateway, my home devices will all be connected in zone B. Only the work computer workstation will be hardwired to Zone A, no wifi, no nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Computers are in the LAN and have firewalls you speak of.

Most computers have individual firewalls in the OS, ensuring they are turned on is advisable. They help prevent the spread of malware.

The windows one is on by default, but when you join a network you should choose not to be discoverable. It's possible to review that setting and change it.

I wouldn't worry so much about "consumer grade firewall". They are quite dumb and simplistic which is more secure for home users - it's harder to accidentally expose yourself.

Other than that Steffen's answer describes another valid option.

Comment: On a corporate LAN where the goal to achieve is securing a sub-network, one should never trust on "individual firewalls" as you described because of human errors: a sysadmin/user may turn firewall off for testing or whatever and may forget to turn it back on which may lead to big breaches. A "top-level" subnet firewall prevent such scenario.

Answer (score -2):

> Is this a sensible approach?

No. If you wish to up the security posture of your home network, then I would rather advice you to harden the devices on that network, such as turn off unnecessary services, install A\V software, etc. Placing firewall on the edge (internet in this case) of network does not matter unless a proper ACL is written and features correctly used in order to leverage protection it offers.

> Is this an overkill, or is there a better way to isolate home/work
>   terminal from household internet devices?

It's not overkill, it's simply not the most effective approach. Approach to securing any network is basically the same - Harden, Defence in Depth, MFA authentication, Encryption.

Comment: Rashad, thanks for the response. Assume that the devices in the home cannot all be hardend, iphones, PS4, security cams probably made in China, Amazon Alexa, smart door locks, smart garage door openers, smart light bulbs, robotic wifi vacuums, and the list keeps growing. The best I can do to harden devices is keep firmware updated, but there are other people in the house and that is not an option, hence, my proposed solution. My concern is consumer devices that act as gateways into my LAN.

Comment: Devil07, You can reduce the surface of attack by cutting down ports and protocols not used by the said devices to function on the firewall. The consumer device that act as gateway to your LAN is a router used to connect to internet provider I assume? Most of these devices in a price range 50-75$ and up does support ACL which you can use for these purposes. Non jailbroken\rooted smartphone are quite hard to infect out of the blue by the way.